# Is it possible to load-balance requests in phusion passenger based on params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

We assume the application receives requests to operate on a limited number of resources, which support just one operation at a time. An example is:

```
/GET do_stuff?resource=A&other_params
/GET do_stuff?resource=B&other_params
```

The idea is that the operation from resource A should be placed in process A and request for B in process B. If any other request is received for resource A, it should be in queue in process A. Kind of guaranteeing a synchronous operating mode for each resource.

This could be attained with Rabbit MQ or other similar approaches, or even with discrete programming outside phusion, but it would be interesting and practical in my case to have a way to do this straight from application config, or any other idea.

To make things a little clearer, the resource variable can have roughly 500 values, so hard-coding or using the app group name option is not suitable.

The logic itself should look like :

```
incoming request 
      if there is a process that is running a request for the resource 
         put request into process queue
      else 
         spawn or use free process
```

The number of processes should not be so high at one moment since the requests will arrive at almost random times.

Comment: How do you run your passenger - inside apache/nginx or standalone with reverse proxy?

Comment: In this case, inside nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Passenger balances requests by request queues, one per application group. Documentation [here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_app_group_name) states that group can be assigned per server/location/if statement, so first to try will be nginx config like:

```
location /do_stuff {
  if($arg_resource ~ (A|B) ){
    passenger_app_group_name "some_appliation_group_key_for_resource_$arg_resource";
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I didn't add all the information (I will edit the question). The answer is viable for a scenario where you have a small number of applications. Already research this approach from [phusion docs(https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/ruby/request_load_balancing.html). But consider a larger number of resource(as mentioned in the question), between 50 - 1000, without me knowing the full list.